# faild to build body in activemq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, activemq-classic

I want use ActiveMQ in .net core,i use `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ` for doing this but I have problem.
I see this error in ActiveMQ admin console:

```
Cannot display ObjectMessage body. Reason: Failed to build body from bytes. Reason: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00010000
```

thats part of my code for doing this:

```
private const String QUEUE_DESTINATION = "test-queue";
private IConnection _connection;
private ISession _session;
public MessageQueue()
{
    IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=5000000");
    _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    _connection.Start();
    _session = _connection.CreateSession();
}
```

```
IDestination dest = _session.GetQueue(QUEUE_DESTINATION);
using (IMessageProducer producer = _session.CreateProducer(dest))
{
    var objectMessage = producer.CreateObjectMessage(newDoc);
    producer.Send(objectMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the admin console can't display the body of an ObjectMessage isn't really an error. It's the expected behavior. Remember, from the broker's perspective the message body is just an array of bytes. It could be text data (encoded many different ways), image data, custom binary data, etc. The broker has no idea how to decode it. It will *try* to display the body as text, but if it fails it won't try anything else.

To be clear, in order to see the contents of an ObjectMessage the web console would have to have the object's definition in order to deserialize it. There is no mechanism to tell the web console about arbitrary data formats so it can deserialize message bodies reliably (other than simple text). This is one reason, among many, to avoid ObjectMessage.

I recommend you use a simple text format (e.g. JSON, XML) to represent your data and send that in your message rather than using ObjectMessage.

Comment: yes, that's right.but is there anyway I see my object in ActiveMQ?? I have simple object with field of string